# How to check if key is pressed while other code is running

Tags: python

In the code below, the only way to get out of the loop is by holding q and pressing enter on the last input. But is there a way to check if a key is pressed while any other code is running?

```
import keyboard, time
while True:
   if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
      break
   str1 = input('Type your first name: ')
   time.sleep(5)
   str2 = input('Type your last name: ')
```

Comment: Why not check if `str1` is `"q"` then `break`?

Comment: @DSteman It is just some random template code to show that something is happening. I want to have other meaningful code, but if the user wants to exit they can just hold q at any moment.

Comment: Isn't that the same as ctrl+c? You just want another key for that

Comment: @DSteman Yes and no. I don't want it to fully exit the code, I just want to end the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like these :

```py
import keyboard, time
from threading import Thread

def execute_questions():
    while True:
        str1 = input('Type your first name: ')
        str2 = input('Type your last name: ')



t =Thread(target=execute_questions)
t.daemon = True 
t.start()

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        #stops the thread
        print('\nprogram finish')
        break
```